# GoogleAuthProvider - Option to choose account

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, google-identity

I'm working on a project in Flutter. I use this code:

```
_googleAuthProvider.setCustomParameters({'prompt': 'select_account'});

    UserCredential userCredential;

    if (kIsWeb) {
      userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithPopup(_googleAuthProvider);
    } else {
      userCredential =
          await _firebaseAuth.signInWithProvider(_googleAuthProvider);
    }
```

On web I can choose which account I want to log in with. On mobile (iOS & Android) I don't get this choice and automatically log in with the previous logged in user.

How can I ensure that I can choose which account I log in with on mobile as well?

I tried several things including changing the customParameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  googleSignIn.disconnect();

  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount =
      await googleSignIn.signIn();

  if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
        idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken);

    userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  }
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Method

```
void _signInWithGoogle() async {
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser =
await GoogleSignIn(scopes: <String>["email"]).signIn();
if (googleUser != null) {
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
  await googleUser.authentication;
  final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken);
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
  String fullName = googleUser.displayName!;
  var names = fullName.split(' ');
  var firstName = names[0];
  var image = googleUser.photoUrl;
  var email = googleUser.email;
```

}

When you click on logout use this

```
GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: <String>['email'],);
googleSignIn.signOut();
```