# Google Auth Not working in flutter even after adding the SHA Keys

Tags: flutter, google-oauth

i am trying to login with google and i have followed the steps to setup.

- Created app in firebase
- Enable the Google Authentication
- Generated the debug SHA keys and added to the firebase

Still getting the following error. Is there any solution for that?

[image]

I tried to generate the SHA keys from cmd but the keys were same and i tried to change the code but still it doesn't worked.

Comment: Please share your code. what you have to implemented

Comment: GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
    GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth = await googleUser?.authentication;

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        idToken: googleAuth?.idToken, accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken);
    await signInWithGoogle(credential);

Comment: Please check my git repo

https://github.com/SharmaJatin1997/flutter_google_login

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75694206/googleauthprovider-option-to-choose-account/75696347#75696347

Check this answer also